# Writing to the Apache error.log file from Mod_Wsgi

Tags: django, ubuntu, apache2, mod-wsgi, error-logging

I am having issues setting up my wsgi file so I wanted to output messages to the log file.  I found this page http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques, but when I try to use the code:

```
print >> sys.stderr, "application debug #3"
```

in my project.wsgi file, the message is not pushed to the error.log on apache restart. The site is being served correctly.  What do I need to do to make the logging work?

P.S. I am on Ubuntu 10.10 serving a Django site.

Comment: "the same messages as every previous apache restart"?

Comment: What I mean to say is that, my "application debug #3" didn't make it to the error.log when I restarted apache.

Comment: Where is that line in your code? Why are you expecting that specific code to be executed when Apache/mod_wsgi is being restarted?

Comment: That line is in my .wsgi file. Everything in that file seems to be executed when I restart apache. Maybe I'm mistaken?

Comment: The WSGI script file is normally only loaded when the first request arrives for that specific application and not automatically when processes start, ie., not when Apache is restarted. You can force it to be loaded on process start if mod_wsgi is configured appropriately, but isn't the default. Nothing in the WSGI script file is executed on a process shutdown. To have that happen you would need to register an atexit callback. See 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/RegisteringCleanupCode#Cleanup_On_Process_Shutdown'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WSGI script file is normally only loaded when the first request arrives for that specific application and not automatically when processes start, ie., not when Apache is restarted. You can force it to be loaded on process start if mod_wsgi is configured appropriately, but isn't the default. Nothing in the WSGI script file is executed on a process shutdown. To have that happen you would need to register an atexit callback. See 'code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/…;. – Graham Dumpleton

Graham Dumpleton is a genius!